# Why do processes not work for me the second time with vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a small Vue application, with a parent component which has more components immersed in it, Initially I get some product data from the database, from these elements stored in an array calculates with vue.

It works well the first time, but the second time my data is not reactive, checking the console with vue devtools, the property changes, but on the screen they are not changed.

What can I be doing wrong? , what I do at the end of the first time, is to reset the values of the elements of data () {} in the following way.

```
 this.showModalOptions= false;
 this.showModalType= false;
 this.udpdateprecios = false;
 this.products=[];
 this.productsselect= [];
 this.productselect={};
 this.type= {};
 this.obtenerProducts(); //get productos y assign to array products
```

method obtenerProducts

```
 obtenerProducts(){
        axios.get('/api/products/all')
        .then((result) => {
            this.products= result.data.productos;

        });
    },
```

declare data()

```
data() {
        return {
            products: [],
            productselect: {},
            type: {},
            productsselect: [], 
            showModalOptions: false,
            showModalType: false,

        };
    },
```

I can not add an example that works for me, maybe it is not the way to reset the array or objects with which they stop being reactive?

Comment: Could you post the gist for obtenerProducts?

Comment: @Austio yes, I already added it to my question

Comment: Is the `this.products` variable spelled consistently throughout the component? In your snippets I see both: `this.products = []` and `this.productos = results.data.productos`

Comment: Sorry, the code is superficial portions I was wrong to edit the question.

Comment: @tony19 ,I have already added it to my question

Comment: The assignment looks fine so far, but I think we need more context. Can you show your template? It would be even better if you could provide a fiddle/codepen/codesandbox link.

Answer (score 0):

If as you said, the property changes and the screen stay the same , maybe you should try `vm.$forceUpdate()` or `vm.$nextTick(yourFunction)` to refresh the event queue.

Comment: if I tried with vm. $ forceUpdate () without results. I added it in the main single file component. Is that where I put it?

Comment: If you use it in the SFC, you should use `this.$forceUpdate()` , the same with `this.$nextTick(function(){})`

Comment: You could place your answer based on your comment. How could or should I perform those steps?